# Saving filters on transferred iPhone image

Tags: images, iphone

When you save an image from your iPhone to your Mac you lose the filter applied to the image.   This appears to be by [design](http://www.cultofmac.com/231726/ios-7s-new-photo-filters-are-lossless-keeping-original-photo-untouched/).

Has anyone figured out how to get around this and transfer the image to your Mac/PC with the filter applied?

Answer (score 1):

I know its not practical but you could email your self the photos or upload them to the cloud i guess. You could also take a screen shot of your photos which is basically taking a picture of a picture

Update: I found someone else who had the problem https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5369677

Comment: Yup that works..  not the ideal solution but it works..

Answer (score 0):

Emailing works, but is obviously tedious.  I tried the cloud, because I thought at least I could dump a bunch of photos at once from my iphone 6.  Nope.  Only lets you do one at a time, took about 10-15 seconds each.  Terrible.  Then after doing a few, I noticed it wasn't even keeping the filters afterall.  So you have two choices- email all the photos from your phone to yourself, download them, then save them wherever you keep photos, or not care about having filters.  Apple's hardware is fine, everything else is crap. They want you to only use their products, and make you jump through insane amounts of hoops even when you are using their products.  Just give up on life if you try using someone else's products with theirs.

Comment: This could be improved by removing the irrelevant parts and focusing on the actual answer.